# How do I change this query to make it return records that meet the `minPrice` condition even if the `keywords` value is null?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, entitymanager

I don't know if this is a problem that is specific to Google App Engine for Java, but if the value set as the `keywords` parameter is a null String, then nothing is returned from the query, even if a `minPrice` is set.

How do I change this query to make it return records that meet the `minPrice` condition even if the `keywords` value is null? Ideally I would somehow use the same query for both conditions without creating separate queries based on a null String condition.

```
Query qry = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Test p 
 WHERE keywords = :keywords and price >= :minPrice");

qry.setParameter("keywords", keywords);
qry.setParameter("minPrice", Integer.parseInt(minPrice));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the way the GAE datastore works (most relational databases work that way too, btw!): nulls are *not* equal to anything, so the `keywords = :keywords` part of your query is false on records with null `keywords` -- since that part is false, so is the `and`, of course.

You'll need two queries, one for `keywords = :keywords` and one for the "is null" check, and use their two disjoint result sets (Python GAE simulates an "IN" operator in app-level code, which I believe Java GAE doesn't, but since the sets *are* disjoint in this case there's really no mystery or difficulty to it anyway;-).

**Edit**: it's a simulated `IN` (which would be usable here) in Python, *not* `OR`; the Java equivalent of that app-level-simulated `IN` is actually `contains`.

Comment: Hmm, my understanding and experience (in the Python runtime) is that you can query for entities whose value for this property is `None` (just like any other value).  The only thing you cannot query for is entities which *omit* a property entirely.

Comment: @David, true, there _is_ a distinction (in the underlying datastore and therefore in both languages) between an absent field (unsearchable) and one that's null (`None` in Python), which _is_ searchable.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the question now - I didn't realize he wanted it to match the a non-null `keywords` parameter *or* `null`.  Oops :p.